# Best database design for storing whitelisted customer

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a case when a marketplace have many promotion. Each promotion is eligbile for only whitelisted customer. There is probability that a customer is whitelisted for more than one promotion. And also it must handle high traffic since customer always entered promotion code to see if its eligible or not. Currently I implemented a whitelist_customer table, with column 'customer_id' with unique index, and 'values' column with text[] array data type. For example, in one row I can  store customer_id '1' and this customer eligible for 3 promotions so I store 'values' with 'PROMOCODE1','PROMOCODE2','PROMOCODE3'.

So when customer_id '1' enter the code PROMOCODE2, it will inquire the eligibility by searching by its customer_id, and then search using @> (contains).

Is this approach is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
arrays break the [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) rule in database design (repeating values).
also, to search in array takes time.

The best solution would be with a table where each promotion is in a different row. This table will have a composite primary key (that means there will be an index on the two columns as well)

```
CREATE TABLE customer_promotion (
    cust_id int,
    promotion varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(cust_id, promotion)
);
```

searching for specific cust_id and promotion becomes trivial

Comment: There is a case which two promotion have almost similiar whitelisted customer as well. In our case a promotion has an average of 5 millions customer. So if we want to add another promotion with same whitelisted it will create another 5 millions rows. And every month probably there will be 4-5 new promotion. Is that the best approach?

Comment: the difference between the two designs in terms of memory size aren't that great. you will need to estimate how many total rows you will have. Pg can handle a table with few hundred millions. if it's more, it will have a hard time with arrays as well and  you need to consider noSql solutions like Apache Cassandra

Comment: Yep nosql solutions will do very good for this case.  Thank you for the insight. I will stick to the composite primary key as well. As for the indexing, I read about its better in postgres if we build separate index for each column right rather than make an index for 2 columns.